# Map and render two different arrays in the same component - React

Tags: reactjs

I just started learning React and I'm having issues understanding how to map and and render two different arrays in the same component. In my CMS I have 3 entries containing a title and a description each. I am calling them from GraphQL with the var `data`. The component `SectionLeft` has a grid container with `threeFeatures` as className. In my homepage I am passing the content to the grid container with the prop `bottomcontent`. I am passing the component `SingleFeature` in array which is my grid column and will contain an icon, a title and a description, it will repeat 3 times and compose my 3 column x 1 row grid. The component `SingleFeature` has the prop `children` which should contain an array map of the constant `iconList` containing 3 different svg icon components. I can't understand how to write a multiple array map for the component `SingleFeature` which will display the same `data` array displayed below for the props `feature` and `details`, but will render the 3 components for `children` in array. Any explanation would be really appreciated. Thank you.

**homepage.js**

```
import IconOne from "../components/icons/icon-one"

import IconTwo from "../components/icons/icon-two"

import IconThree from "../components/icons/icon-three"

export const iconList = [IconOne, IconTwo, IconThree]

export default function Home({data}) {

  return (
    <div>
      <SectionLeft bottomcontent =

      {data.allContentfulHomepageWordpressFeatures.edges.map(edge => (

          <SingleFeature
          
          children = {
            ...iconList array...
          }
          feature = {
            edge.node.feature
          }
          details = {
            edge.node.description
          }
          />

        ))
      }
     />
   );
}
```

**section-left.js**

```
export default function SectionLeft(props) {

    return (
                <div className="threeFeatures">{props.bottomcontent}</div>

    );
}
```

**single-feature.js**

```
export default function SingleFeature(props) {
    return(
        <div>
        {props.children}
        <h3>{props.feature}</h3>
        <p>{props.details}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**GraphQL query**

```
export const query = graphql`

  allContentfulHomepageSpeedFeatures {
    edges {
      node {
        feature
        description
      }
    }
  }

}

`
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in `homepage.js`.

Comment: after every ***impot*** line use ***;*** because you'll get another error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
data.allContentfulHomepageWordpressFeatures.edges.map((edge, index) => (

      <SingleFeature
      
      children = {
        iconList[index]
      }
      feature = {
        edge.node.feature
      }
      details = {
        edge.node.description
      }
      />

    ))
```

map passes the index of the element in the mapped array as a second parameter to your arrow function.

Comment: Perfect, it worked perfectly, I just had to write the constant like that:

const iconList = [<IconOne />, <IconTwo />, <IconThree />]

Comment: Right! I forgot that you are passing icons as components directly to children. I concentrated no the mapping part.